# Select and update a couple of rows in MySQL without collision

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, mariadb

Please consider there is stash table which is full of records. There will be many concurrent requests to pick and own some records from the stash table.

I'm not sure and don't really know how I could use Transcations to combine select and update to do what I said without any coalitions.

For example, that's my table:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | is_taken |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | a    |        1 |
|  2 | b    |        0 |
|  3 | c    |        0 |
|  4 | aa   |        1 |
|  5 | bb   |        0 |
|  6 | dd   |        0 |
|  7 | e    |        0 |
|  8 | ff   |        0 |
+----+------+----------+
```

--

```
-- first select them
SELECT * FROM `STASH` WHERE `is_taken` = 0 LIMIT 2
-- then update and take them to stop others to taking them
UPDATE `STASH` SET `is_taken` = 1 WHERE `is_taken` = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the table as a queue of actions and they are short:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
act on them
DELETE ...; -- assuming you are finished with them.
COMMIT;
```

And check at each stage for errors.  If you get a deadlock or lock-wait-timeout, restart.

If actions take a long time, then a different technique should be used.

So, please elaborate on

- How many rows typically (and max) are in the table
- How many rows you want to pick at once
- How long it takes to 'process' a row
- Whether you can delete the row when finished.

Different techniques work better, depending on your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider adding an owner column, if it does not already have one, to the table. Then just run the update statement, setting the owner and that the row is taken. You should have  unique owner per logical transaction.

```
update stash set owner = some_owner, is_taken = 1 where is_taken = 0 limit 2;
```

*This statement should be tested under your expected concurrency load to see how it performs.*

Then select those rows

```
select * from stash where owner = some_owner and is_taken = 1;
```

Then when it is time to release, using the ids from the above select

```
update stash set owner = null, is_taken = 0 where id in (...);
```